# Power steering fluid

Tags: nissan, power-steering, altima

How long can I drive my car if power steering fluid is orange? I just noticed it and found out through Google I may have a leak in hose, can't do anything for a couple days, is that bad for my car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Power steering used to use auto transmission oil which was red : What makes you think there is a problem ?

Comment: Why “used to” ? Still do... that’s what is in mine...

Comment: @blacksmith37 - When air gets introduced into the power steering fluid, it turns an orangish color.

Answer (score 3):

You may have an air leak in your power steering system, or the fluid just may be old. Look in your service history to see if you have any details of when it was last changed. It's possible you've been driving a long time with orange fluid.

Unless your power steering pump is whining or you're having steering issues there's no emergency, just get it checked at a convenient time in the next few weeks.

Comment: I agree that it's not an emergency, but if you don't know when the fluid has been changed, you should change it when possible.

Comment: Absolutely, is it's orange it needs changing. If it's been changed recently then there's a mechanical issue of some kind that needs fixing.